# Razor pages get property query naming

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-5

In Razor pages I would like to get a specific behaviour on how query parameters are generated, for example I would like to get this kind of url:

```
https://localhost:5001/admin/users?q=1&page=5
```

In my page model I have two properties bound for the `OnGetAsync` method.
I tried giving the properties custom naming with

- `[Display(Name = "...")]`
- `[FromQuery(Name = "...")]`
- `[ModelBinding(Name = "...")]`
- `[BindProperty(Name = "...")]`

I even tried using combinations of this properties such as `BindProperty` with `FromQuery`.
What I noticed is that when using `[FromQuery]` if I manually write the url in the browser the property gets the correct name but when generating it for a form or an url I could not get it with the right name.

This is my page:

```
public class Users : PageModel
{        

    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public Users(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    [FromQuery(Name = "q")]
    [BindProperty(Name = "q", SupportsGet = true)]
    public string Search { get; set; }

    public IdentityUser CurrentUser { get; set; }
    
    [FromQuery(Name = "page")]
    [BindProperty(Name = "page", SupportsGet = true)]
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; } = 1;

    public ICollection<IdentityUser> Users { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        CurrentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

        IList<IdentityUser> users;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Search))
        {
            users = await _userManager.Users
                .OrderBy(x => x.UserName)
                .ThenBy(x => x.Email)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            users = await _userManager.Users.Where(
                    x => x.Username.Contains(Search)
                            || x.Email.Contains(Search)
                )
                .OrderBy(x => x.UserName)
                .ThenBy(x => x.Email)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the related html:

```
@page
@model Pages.Users

<form method="get" class="mt-5 mb-2">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label class="sr-only" asp-for="Search"></label>

            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <div class="input-group-text">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <input asp-for="Search" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<ul class="pagination">
    @for (var i = 1; i < Model.TotalPages; i++)
    {
        <li class="page-item @(Model.CurrentPage == i ? "active" : "")">
            <a asp-page="/Users" asp-route-search="@Model.Search" asp-route-currentpage="@i" class="page-link">@i</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

The generated name and id in the form input is `Search` instead of `q`

The generated url in the pagination is `/users?search=aaa&currentpage=2` instead of `/users?q=aaa&page=1`

Comment: The form knows nothing about your C# code, it uses the `name` attribute of the `input`, which is 'Search'. Change that to 'q'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The routing system in Razor Pages (which is what is used to generate URLs from the anchor tag helper) doesn't like `page` as a route parameter, so you will have to construct your query strings yourself, if you must have `page` as a key:

`<a href="/users?q=@Model.Search&page=@1">@i</a>`

The alias passed to the `name` property on the `BindProperty` attribute only works one way. When you use input tag helpers, they generate `name` and `id` attributes based on the name of the public property that the `BindAttribute` has been applied to. If you want a different value in your form fields, you can override that by setting the `name` attribute manually.

`<input asp-for="Search" name="q" class="form-control">`

Comment: Since I need to use this kind of system on most all of the project, is it a bad idea to write my own TagHelper?

Comment: I can't really comment without knowing the full details of what you are doing, but based purely on the scenario in your question, I can't see a case for creating a custom tag helper.